# How to unsubscribe from events without disrupting other instances of the same plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have created a jQuery plugin which needs to respond to the resizing of the browser window. It subscribes to the event using jQuery's event namespacing mechanism:

```
var $window = $(window);
$window.on("resize.myPlugin", function(e) {
    // my resize code
});
```

So when the plugin is destroyed, I can gracefully unsubscribe without disrupting other plugins:

```
$window.off("resize.myPlugin");
```

However, in this case, what happens if I have multiple instances of the same plugin at the same time? Calling `off` like above will also unsubscribe their event handlers because they use the same namespace.

How can I unsubscribe from events without disrupting other instances of the same plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect other instances of the same plugin to coexist, you can prefix the events with a random namespace, thus avoiding disconnecting all of them.

Edit: posting from mobile, took my time writing. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd pick a unique ID for each plugin instance (produced by a shared generator) and use a kind of "sub-namespace" by extending the namespace to `resize.myPlugin_instanceId`:

```
var $window = $(window);
$window.on("resize.myPlugin_"+uniqueInstanceId, function(e) {
    // my resize code
});

$window.off("resize.myPlugin_"+uniqueInstanceId);
```

Exactly how you generate and access this ID would depend a bit on your specific plugin architecture, I suppose, but I'm guessing it should be fairly straightforward.